# Create an action - Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I created a bundle backend/main/:

my app/routing.yml

```
backendmain:
    resource: "@backendmainBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /main
```

my backend/Bundle/mainBundle/config/routing.yml:

```
backendmain_homepage:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: backendmainBundle:Default:index }
```

my backend/Bundle/mainBundle/DefaultController.php:

```
namespace backend\Bundle\mainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

    class DefaultController extends Controller
    {
        public function indexAction($name)
        {
            return $this->render('backendmainBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
        }

            public function testAction($name)
        {
            return $this->render('backendmainBundle:Default:test.html.twig', array());
        }
    }
```

How can I call the action test in my browser?

Sorry, but was Fabien on drugs, when he created Symfony2? Symfony 1.4 was so freaking easy!

Comment: -1 should be for very basic thing, clearly given in docs. But my -1 is for last line of your question. If you don't read docs properly doesn't mean creator is on drugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any match in your routes definition for the test action. The only route you added is for the index action. So you need to add something like,

```
backendmain_test:
    pattern:  /test
    defaults: { _controller: backendmainBundle:Default:test }
```

In your `backend/Bundle/mainBundle/config/routing.yml` file so that you can make a call to your test action.

**Update:**
Using annotations

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
backendmain:
    resource: "@backendmainBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
    prefix:   /main
    type:     annotation
```

**DefaultController.php**

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
// ...

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="backendmain_test")
     */
    public function testAction()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: Do I need this to do for every action?

Comment: Yes and you can also use [the annotation (@Route)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html).

Take a deeper look at the [routing section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) of the documentation.

Comment: And no ^^ Fabien wasn't on drugs :) Symfony2 is much more powerful than Symfony 1.4. Go deeper in the documentation and you'll figure out how powerful Symfony2 could be.

Comment: If I get it right, I have to activate them in app/config/routing.yml: backendmain:
    resource: "@backendmainBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
    type:     annotation

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, with annotations routes are defined inside your controller and need to be imported/activated.

Comment: Can you update your post, how I can do this? I did an activation like in you link with: use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19912/discussion-between-ahmed-siouani-and-craphunter)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19942/discussion-between-ahmed-siouani-and-craphunter)